# Do I need to disable 'authorization' to create new users for MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, digital-ocean

I currently got a database that is actively being used on a droplet on Digital Ocean. I have authorization enabled on this mongo droplet.

I would like to create a new user for a new database, however I am getting authorization errors. In [this blog](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-mongodb-on-ubuntu-20-04) on digital ocean it basically says that you are able to create new administrative users when authorization is disabled.

Is is 'safe' to simply disable authorization for a few seconds (even when the database is actively being used), create a new user for a new database en re-enable the authorization and restarting the daemon. Also, is this the 'correct' way?

Comment: How do you connect to the database?

Comment: I tried connecting with `mongo -u AdminReinier -p --authenticationDatabase admin` and creating a new user and that didn't work either though. I believe I did add the role `userAdminAnyDatabase` to the AdminReinier user, so it should be able to create new users.. @WernfriedDomscheit

Comment: You could disable authorization, however change to port to something else and set `net.bindIp: localhost` - then nobody else can connect to the DB while authorization is off. Verify created users with `db.getUsers({showCredentials:true})`

Comment: Thanks. This is what I ended up doing and it worked luckily :).

Answer (score 1):

> Is is 'safe' to simply disable authorization for a few seconds

No, in the same way that it isn't safe to leave the house door open while you run to the store.

Connect as an administrative user and create additional users as needed.

Comment: But whatever I do, I just keep getting authorization errors. When I type `mongo` and do `use admin` and try to create a new user I get the following error: `couldn't add user: command createUser requires authentication`. I only got two users as far as I know, admin (the default one) and one that I made for one particular database....

Comment: @Reinier68 please read and comprehend the answer. Pay extra attention to the sentence starting with "Connect as an administrative user". It means login to mongo as a user with userAdmin privileges. Try to login as a "root" user. It has access to everything. The error you quoted says you connected to mongo without authentication, e.g. as anonymous user with no privileges at all.

Comment: I tried connecting with `mongo -u AdminReinier -p --authenticationDatabase admin` and creating a new user and that didn't work either though. I believe I did add the role `userAdminAnyDatabase` to the AdminReinier user, so it should be able to create new users... @AlexBlex

Comment: what was the error? "that didn't work either" is not very informative.

Answer (score 1):

When authorization is enabled and no user is created  then you can connect without username/password, this is called [Localhost Exception](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-users/#localhost-exception)

However, once the first admin user is created, you cannot connect anymore without valid credentials.

So, when you get an authorization error then an admin user was created already and you have to use this one.